# AnyGantt: getting the date on a point of the gantt chart when clicking with the mouse

Tags: gantt-chart, anychart

Is there a way, in AnyGantt, to get the full date of the point where the mouse was clicked, or where some item has been dropped?

I am trying to do something like 'create a new task on double-click over the gantt chart', but don't know how to get the start date below the cursor.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it goes beyond the functionality of AnyGantt 7.14.3 September 2017. 
Please, contact us *support@anychart.com* to describe in details this feature. We look ahead to implement it in future releases.